# for-each doesn't work for my xslt

Tags: xslt, filemaker

I have a problem I couldn't solve despite extensive searching...
This is a part from an XML.

```
<contributors>
<authors>
<author>Willett, C G</author>
<author>Tepper, J E</author>
<author>Kaufman, D S</author>
<author>Shellito, P C</author>
<author>Eliseo, R</author>
<author>Convery, K</author>
<author>Wood, W C</author>
</authors>
</contributors>
```

I tried to import all authors into a Filemaker cell by using this xsl (excerpt)

```
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="15" NAME="Author" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <COL>
<DATA>
<xsl:for-each select="contributors/authors">
<xsl:value-of select="author">
</xsl:value-of>
</xsl:for-each>
</DATA>
</COL>
```

Unfortunately only the first name is imported. Why? What's missing?

Would be glad if someone could help me...

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate through the `author`s, not through `authors`, because there's only one `authors`, but many `author`s:

```
<xsl:for-each select="contributors/authors/author">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Great thank you! Works! What does the dot(.) stand for in value-of select="." ??

Comment: The dot stands for the current context node (which would be an `author` element in this case).

Comment: And what do I have to do in order to insert a blank space between two authors?

Comment: You can use `concat(., ' ')`.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="15" NAME="Author" TYPE="TEXT"/>
  <COL>
    <DATA>
      <xsl:for-each select="contributors/authors/author">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">; </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </DATA>
  </COL>
```

This would produce a semicolon-separated list of all the author values.  The `<xsl:if>` is there to avoid adding a trailing semicolon after the last author name.